# Angular 2 - how to pass function in *ngFor

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-directives

I need help regarding how i can pass a function in *ngFor loop or any another suggestion ??

I have todo-list Component and a child todo-item component - I want to pass a function which will return a value- Please check the code below:

-- Todo List Component

```
`<div class="list-group">
  <app-todo-item 
    *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i = index"
    [todoItem]="todo"
    [index]="i"></app-todo-item>
</div>`
```

-- Todo Item Component
`

```
<a 
  [routerLink]="index"
  [routerLinkActive]="'list-group-item-warning'"
  class="list-group-item">
  {{ todo.name }}
  <span class="badge badge-pill" 
    [ngClass]="{'badge-success': todo.status === 'active', 'badge-warning': todo.status === 'inactive'}">{{ todo.status }}</span>
  <div class="option-group float-right"> 
    <span class="badge badge-dark">2 days ago myFunction(date)</span>
  </div>
</a>
`
```

Please let me know what possible way i can achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to pass the function to app-todo-item component?

if so you could use `@Output` from angular core

```
// import it inside your component
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'

// declare the function callback you want to recieve
@Output() callback = new EventEmitter();

// to make the callback send data back call, if you want to pass multiple fields put it all inside an object
this.callback.emit(datatobepassed)

// to make use of it do; you need to put $event or else function recieves undefined
<app-todo-item (callback)=”yourfunction($event)”>

// in your parent component
yourfunction(data: any)
{
    // stuff
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: One thing if i want to print my callback function value in todo item template how can do this ??

Comment: does that mean that the callback function sends data back to the `app-todo-item` component?